# Localisation issues with localisation strings

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

Just spend another evening, trying to figure that out.
Here is what I am doing:

1) Creating a clean project with tabbed iOS application in XCode 6.3.1;

2) Under Project/Info/Localisations I am adding another localisation (Russian,German, doesn't matter)

3) In Main.strings file, changing corresponding strings, OR doing exactly the same by Exporting/Importing .xliff file.

4) Deleting app from simulator/device, cleaning project from Product/Clean, deleting derived app data from corresponding folder

5) Changing language in simulator/device

6) Making a run... Still English. Localised strings just wont pick up, no matter what.(even though they are looks just fine trough assistant editor)

What am I doing wrong? Is that suppose to be that complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got update from 6.3.1 to 7.0.1 XCode and the issue is fixed for me.
I am making exactly same steps and got Russian/German/English interface depending on the language I chose in simulator settings.
Guess that is it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running on a device. Xcode 6.x had known issues with the Simulator not showing localizations.

Comment: No luck on real device eather, sorry for not mentioning it